# difference between sklearn.preprocessing.quantile_transform and sklearn.preprocessing.QuantileTransformer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I understand that the difference between these two preprocessing functionalities in sklearn is that the former doesn't have the estimator API, but what is the use case for one versus the other? I guess what I'm really asking is when do you need the API estimator capability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of them is a function (`quantile_transform`):

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e85a6d1f/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py#L2541

and the other is a class (`QuantileTransformer`):

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e85a6d1f/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py#L2132